# Google fonts load ignored when font exists locally

Tags: javascript, css, google-font-api

I am loading 'Nothing you could do' from google fonts which works perfectly in all browsers. However, if I have the font installed on my machine already it uses that instead of the Google one. There are several issues with that, one is that a class with `font-size: 1.45em;` appears way bigger if the font is loaded from the local machine.

I realise that the percentage of people having the font installed would be minimal but still I am just wondering if there is a way to always force a load from Google?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jkxb6/)

Comment: Can u post your code here  or even a fiddle ?

Comment: Edited post and added fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you look at the snippet behind the URL Google gives you to use, it reads (for me -- it appears Google does browser sniffing to not serve Firefox IE-specific workarounds etc):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Nothing You Could Do';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Nothing You Could Do'), 
       local('NothingYouCouldDo'), 
       url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/no...YU.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Lose the two `local` bits and host the CSS yourself, you should be better.

Comment: I tried probably 20 different things I don't know why that didn't cross my mind. Ha, embarrassing... well spotted, thanks.